# accounts-ui and accounts-google does not open up a configuration window when bundled and deployed

Tags: meteor

I am playing with accounts-ui package with accounts-google and I am noticing something strange. When I do "meteor run --port 3001" and go to http://testsite.com:3001, I can click a button that says "Configure Google Login" and configure it. But when I bundle my application up using "meteor bundle myapp.tgz" and run, clicking on that button doesn't open the configuration popup window. If I trace network, I see this latency [image] Any help will be appreciated! [sample site](http://workopenly.com)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure what the question is but let me give it a go:

Since Meteor sends data down on the wire seperate to the HTML & JS: The HTML and JS loads first followed by the data shortly after.

The latency you see there is due to the effects of how the live socket is handled. Meteor will keep the connection 'open' until there is a data change and ask the client to make a new request. What you see reported in the webkit console is the time until a push is sent down to the browser. This is how XHR long polling works. Long polling is the mechanism used to send the data down to the client 'live' at the moment due to a couple of problems with websockets.